# using EasyAlign in a function

Tags: functions, map-operator, plugin-easy-align

I frequently use `EasyAlign` in my tex files to align tables around the `$` delimiter such that this

```
header1 & header2 & header3 \\
data1 & data2 & data3 \\
```

becomes this

```
header1 & header2 & header3 \\
data1   & data2   & data3   \\
```

As I have `EasyAlign` mapped to `gA`, my normal-mode keystrokes to achieve this are `gAip*$`.

So my first thought was `nnoremap <buffer> gT gAip*$`, but this doesn't invoke `EasyAlign`.

As I can `vip` to select inner paragraph, then `:EasyAlign *&` to get the alignment, I tried putting these two in a mapped function in my `vimfiles\ftplugin\tex.vim`:

```
function! EasyAlignTable()
  normal! vip
  EasyAlign *&
endfunction
nnoremap <buffer> gT :call EasyAlignTable()<cr>
```

but this somehow doesn't complete: `vim` remains in visual-mode, and the alignment is not done.

So how do I write this function incorporating `EasyAlign`?

Comment: The reason the mapping doesn't call EasyAlign is because you're using `nnoremap` which ignores existing mappings. Try `nmap`. This is one of those not-too-common cases where you actually don't want the "noremap" variation.

Comment: The issue might be in `EasyAlign` and a range that is in effect when you select a paragraph. Try `'<,'>EasyAlign *&` in your function instead.

Comment: You probably just have to add the full normal-sequence: `normal! vip:EasyAlign *&<CR>`

Comment: @BLayer, nope, the mapping I'm now using is `nnoremap <buffer> gT :normal gAip*&<CR>` successfully over-mapping default `gT`.

Comment: @MaximKim, nope, I tried that, among other ideas with no luck.

Comment: @joharr "Nope"? I was just referring to the `nnoremap gT` mapping in your question which absolutely won't get any mapped keys within. A mapping that uses `:normal` (without `!`) is a totally different situation.

Comment: [Why won't vim recognise a plugin command in the vimrc, but it will recognise it when running?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21322520/why-wont-vim-recognise-a-plugin-command-in-the-vimrc-but-it-will-recognise-it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also try `:normal` command:

```
:normal gAip*&
```

And then `@:` to repeat last command.

Or if you want to map it:

```
nmap <buffer> gT gAip*&
```

Comment: If you're writing a normal-mode mapping, why do `:normal`? Just `nmap <buffer> gT gAip*&<CR>`, though beware of shadowing `gT` builtin

Comment: @D.BenKnoble arrrghhh, indeed :)

Answer (score 0):

I've found a work-around, with minor disadvantage that it's global, and could be overwritten: `let @t = 'gAip*&'`. Then, when my cursor is in the table, I just `@t`.